# Using mod_rewrite to remove file extensions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am looking for a way to remove incoming links that contain file extensions, such as .htm, .html, and .php and to send a 302 response so that the referrer knows to update their links.

For example, www.acmeinc.com/projects.html would redirect to www.acmeinc.com/projects and send a 302 response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the magic:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\. $1 [R=302,L]
```

This rule is only valid for www.acmeinc.com/projects.html and not for www.acmeinc.com/projects.seconddot.html.
If you'd like to rewrite only certain extensions, use this rule.

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\.(html|php|js|foobar) $1 [R=302,L]
```